# Hacked/Stolen Bitcoin privete key-List

Tags: hack

Is there maybe in the existent a list of all hacked/stolen Bitcoin private key?
Thx!

Comment: There is https://allprivatekeys.com/, which also features leaked private keys.

Answer (score 1):

> a list of **all** hacked/stolen Bitcoin private key

(my emphasis)

I am of the view that, in the real world, such a list cannot exist because some victims do not report theft to anyone else. Some victims probably don't know their private key.

Perhaps I am missing something or suffering a lack of imagination but I can't think of any reason why anyone would collect even a partial list of stolen private keys. It's like collecting photos of all torn empty discarded leather-wallets or purses that were ever stolen by pickpockets worldwide in the last two decades. Who would go to the trouble? What would they gain by doing it?